# Adding spaces in a variable

Tags: php, css, string, while-loop

Good evening

I created a while adding spaces in a variable . it's exactly what I need, but now I need to centralize the text between the spaces:

here is the code in PHP:

```
$psn = "ABCDEFGH";
$psnSize = strlen($psn);

while($psnSize <= 20)
{
    $psn = $psn."&nbsp";
    $psnSize++;
}
```

The max size is 20 characters, and I need all psn's have the same size (20 characters)

I'm getting the result but the spaces are added to the end of the text and now I want to distribute the spaces between the text to get it centralized.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Could you give us an example of your desired input and then output values.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me.

I have a div with a text resizing this text.

I want all my variable with the same size(20 characters) if the text in this variable was just 6 characters for example, I want to add 14 spaces in this variable but distribute the spaces to the begin and to the end of this text to get centralized.

Thank you

Comment: Seems that the div should simpy have CSS `text-align:center;` to achieve the desired text centering? Not sure why the attempt to do this at the PHP level, as you may still not achieve the desired result because HTML will "eat" the extra (leading or trailing) spaces, unless you output to a textarea or input.

Comment: I can't use css because I need this align inside the variable. For example: the max size of my variable is 20 characters, then if  I put a text of 6 characters in the variable then I would like to add 7 spaces to the begin and 7 to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all native functions to achieve this:

```
function createLRPadding($str, $chars = 20)
{
    # Count the length
    $strlen =   strlen($str);
    # Don't do anything if you are at the max characters
    if($strlen >= $chars)
        return $str;
    # Get left and right balance
    $len    =   ($chars - $strlen) / 2;
    # Create fills on the left and right of the string and implode them to make one string
    return implode('', array_fill(0,round($len, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP),'&nbsp;')).$str.implode('', array_fill(0,round($len, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN),'&nbsp;'));
}
```

To use:

```
echo createLRPadding('Cool string');
```

To adjust the padding, add a second parameter:

```
echo createLRPadding('Cool string', 40);
```

The first example (default 20 pad) will write:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cool string&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rasclatt! That's exactly what I was looking for. Just one question, I'm getting the result desired but  Why does it appears more then 20 characters when I do `echo strlen(createLRPadding($str, $chars = 20)); `. When I put a text of 12 characters , the quantity shows me 60. Tks

Comment: Because when you put `&nbsp;` those are each 6 characters